# Django DateTimeField default not affecting Time

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

I am following an online tutorial on Django.

Below is my Models script:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Tutorial(models.Model):
    tutorial_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tutorial_content = models.TextField()
    tutorial_published = models.DateTimeField('date published', default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tutorial_title
```

and here is my admin script:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Tutorial

# Register your models here.

class TutorialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ("Title/date",{"fields":["tutorial_title","tutorial_published"]}),
        ("Content", {"fields":['tutorial_content']})
    ]

admin.site.register(Tutorial, TutorialAdmin)
```

My issue is that DateTimeField(default=) is just not working. I am absolutely unable to change the default time in tutorial published. No matter what I put in default, nothing changes. It's always 16:39:02. This isn't a time zone difference. I have no clue what is causing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's probably the **time** you did `makemigrations` - Look in you're app migrations and see if that time is in there, I'm actually curious

Comment: @nealium, doesn't seem to be. The time doesn't line up with any migrations in the migrations folder. Regardless though, I don't know why default=datetime.now wouldn't override this

Comment: wow.. wack. I think you're best bet would be to just **not** have a default and just always set it in the Form or View- that's what I always do

Answer (score 0):

Try define your model field as

```
models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: This throws a field error: FieldError at /admin/main/tutorial/2/change/
'tutorial_published' cannot be specified for Tutorial model form as it is a non-editable field. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class TutorialAdmin.